# Alternate expressions for "a little while"

Tags: colloquial-language

I noticed in my daily Japanese there are many opportunities where I want to express the concept of "in a little while". For example:

> Let's go home in a little while.

Typically I would say this using the following Japanese:

> もう少しで帰ろうね。

I think this is somewhat natural (if I am wrong please let me know), but I am looking for other similar phrases that are also natural and appropriate for everyday spoken conversation.

How are these?

> もう少ししたら帰ろうね。
>
> もう少し経ったら帰ろうね。

I think I can replace 少し in the above expressions with ちょっと, but I am looking for alternate ways to express a similar idea.

Comment: もう少しで帰ろう is not wrong but もう少ししたら is more common. もう少しで fits with future tense or unrealized past e.g. もう少しで できる (It will be complete - ), もう少しで できた (it would be complete - ) rather than invitation or order.

Answer (score 2):

All the phrases you have listed are natural and you can surely replace 「[少]{すこ}し」 by 「ちょっと」, too, in your examples.

We may have a couple of more, but that will be about it.

もうすぐ

もうすぐしたら

[間]{ま}もなく

（もう）間もなくしたら

（もう）しばらくしたら

Note: 「間もなく」 would sound slightly less conversational than the other options.

Comment: Does "もうすぐ" have more of an "immediate" ("right away") connotation compared to もうすこし?

Comment: also, does "しばらく" have a "longer" connotation than the others?

Comment: One more question. When do I need to use "で"? It seems to me like "もう少しで行く" is correct while in the case of "もうすぐ行くよ", で is not needed. Can you please confirm?